# What is the difference of those code snippets?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, geometry, indices

The following code snippets are my attempts to get the triangles from indices and vertices. The `indices` vector contains the number of the vertex. The `vertices` vector contains the coordinates where three of them make one vertex. Together three vertices make up a triangle.

The first snippet works but I would like to not use the additional vector.

```
vector<float> coords;
for(unsigned int i : indices)
{
    coords.push_back(vertices[3 * i + 0]);
    coords.push_back(vertices[3 * i + 1]);
    coords.push_back(vertices[3 * i + 2]);
}
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < coords.size(); i += 9)
{
    triangles->addTriangle(
        btVector3(coords[i + 0], coords[i + 1], coords[i + 2]),
        btVector3(coords[i + 3], coords[i + 4], coords[i + 5]),
        btVector3(coords[i + 6], coords[i + 7], coords[i + 8])
    );
}
```

The second snippet doesn't work, it results in an access violation.

```
float coords[9];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 9)
{
    for(int n = 0, j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k, ++n)
            coords[n] = vertices[3 * indices[i + n] + k];

    triangles->addTriangle(
        btVector3(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]),
        btVector3(coords[3], coords[4], coords[5]),
        btVector3(coords[6], coords[7], coords[8])
    );
}
```

I haven't found the difference. Why isn't the second snippet working?

Comment: @Jon. I didn't knew that this page exist. How can we move the question?

Comment: In the second example, you're not using `j` that I can see?

Comment: @Jon ["5. To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site) No, it doesn't.

Comment: @John That's right. `j` just makes sure to run that loop three times. But since the overall number of iterations from `0` to `9` is needed, there is the `n` variable.

Comment: @Dukeling: Hey, thanks for the heads up! I spend a very tiny amount of time on codereview and didn't know.

Comment: If your indices.size() is not a multiple of 9, then both codes are wrong, and it just so happened that the second one was more prone to access violation due to the internal disposition of memory allocated.

Comment: @Arthur The first code is right since `coords` is guaranteed to be a multiple of 9. `indices` is only guaranteed to be a multiple of 3. Since three elements make up one triangle, I should increment `i` by 3 instead of 9. That fixed my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coords[n] = vertices[3 * indices[i + n] + k];
```

should be

```
coords[n] = vertices[3 * indices[i + j] + k];
```

Comment: That is right. Moreover, `i` must be incremented by 3 instead of 9.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating `i` from `0` to `indices.size()` in steps of `i += 9` but accessing `indices[i + n]` which is very likely out of bounds.

Comment: The variable `n` should be in range `0` to `9` so that `i + n` is still in range `0` to `indices.size()`. Is that wrong?

Comment: Depending on your `indices.size()`, `i` can become as large as `indices.size() - 1` if you add `9` you should be out of bounds.

Comment: You are right. I the issue is to `i` is incremented by 9 instead of 3. But a triangle is made out of three indices not nine.